# Закрепление футера к низу

Tags: css

Футер подымается к вверху, нужно чтобы он постоянное оставался в низу.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  max-width: 1920px;
  background-color: #EFFFF4;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 135%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
  /* InternetExplor 8 */
}

a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a,
a:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all.0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all.0s ease;
  -o-transition: all.0s ease;
  -ms-transition: all.0s ease;
  transition: all.0s ease;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}


/* Стили для Footer */

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #005CFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #BFE7E9;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

footer #social {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

footer #social img {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

footer #Vk img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

footer #rights {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

#page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

footer,
#page-wrap:after {
  height: 10px
}

#page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div id="Vk">
      <a href="http://vk.com" title="Группа Вк" target="_blank">
        <img src="/img/vk.png" alt="Вк" title="Вк">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="social">
      <a href="http://facebook.com" title="Группа Facebook" target="_blank">
        <img src="/img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook">
      </a>
      <a href="http://twitter.com" title="Группа Twitter" target="_blank">
        <img src="/img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="rights">
      Все права защищены &copy;
      <?=date ('Y')?>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: как интересно. вопрос по css, метка по php, а разметка html и вовсе отсутствует.

Comment: так html будет или придумывать надо самим? или в мозг к тебе лезть и выуживать разметку оттуда? или ты сам себе не хочешь помочь?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский html футера?

Comment: Почитай как создать [mcve]

Comment: @AKNYT Именно так

Comment: @Byulent добавил